# XML-SAX Error: Not an ARRAY reference

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

(WinXP Pro, ActivePerl 5.10.1, and XML-SAX 0.96 used)

MyXML.xml as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <subItem>
    <bib>0006</bib>
    <name>Stanley Cheruiyot Teimet</name>
    <team>肯尼亚</team>
    <time>2:17:59</time>
    <rank>1</rank>
    <comment />
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <distance>Full</distance>
    <year>2010</year>
  </subItem>
</DocumentElement>
```

MyPerl.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;

open FILE, ">myXML.txt" or die $!;

my $tree = XMLin('./myXML.xml');
print Dumper($tree);

print FILE "\n";

for (my $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
{
    print  FILE "('$tree->{subItem}->[$i]->{distance}')";

}

close FILE;
```

Output:

```
D:\learning\perl\im>mar.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'subItem' => {
                         'distance' => 'Full',
                         'time' => '2:17:59',
                         'name' => 'Stanley Cheruiyot Teimet',
                         'bib' => '0006',
                         'comment' => {},
                         'team' => '肯尼亚',
                         'rank' => '1',
                         'year' => '2010',
                         'gender' => 'Male'
                       }
        };
Not an ARRAY reference at D:\learning\perl\im\mar.pl line 41.
```

I don't know what the Array reference means? The `Dumper()` works well.But can't print the data to TXT file.

Actually, the sample code ran well days before, Then I remember I upgrade my Komodo Edit from V5. to newest V6.

Today, I just try to improve the script, at the beginning stage, I fixed another error. "Could not find ParserDetails.ini" with google help. (I didn't get the error before!)

But now I get the ARRAY reference error. I already reinstalled my XML-SAX via PPM just now. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole stack for XML parsing that you have set up works fine, as the dump of the parsed tree shows. XML::SAX is not the cause of the problem, and it is only involved indirectly.

The error comes simply from improper access to the data structure which was generated by XML::Simple.

I can guess what happened. In an earlier version of your program, you had the `ForceArray` option enabled (that is a good practice, see [OPTIONS](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple#OPTIONS) and [STRICT_MODE](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple#STRICT_MODE) in XML::Simple), and the algorithm for traversing the parsed tree also was written to take this into account, i.e. there is array access involved.

In the current version of your program `ForceArray` is not enabled, but the traversing algorithm does not match the data structure any more. I suggest to re-enable options that are recommended in the documentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use IO::File qw();
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use autodie qw(:all);

my $xs   = XML::Simple->new(ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => {}, KeepRoot => 1);
my $tree = $xs->parse_file('./myXML.xml');

{
    open my $out, '>', 'myXML.txt';
    $out->say;
    for my $subitem (@{ $tree->{DocumentElement}->[0]->{subItem} }) {
        $out->say($subitem->{distance}->[0]); # 'Full'
    }
}
```

The tree looks like this now:

```
{
    'DocumentElement' => [
        {
            'subItem' => [
                {
                    'distance' => ['Full'],
                    'time'     => ['2:17:59'],
                    'name'     => ['Stanley Cheruiyot Teimet'],
                    'bib'      => ['0006'],
                    'comment'  => [{}],
                    'team'     => ["\x{80af}\x{5c3c}\x{4e9a}"],
                    'rank'     => ['1'],
                    'year'     => ['2010'],
                    'gender'   => ['Male']
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, You code works quite well. And finally I found that my original code also works well ONLY when Xml element subItem named with Caps Letters. Like *bib* -> *Bib*; *name* -> *Name*.  The Bib and Name cames from my Excel file. I don't know the special Caps Naming rule. That's why I meet this trouble. Thank you anyway, You taught me `FourceArray`.